# How to suppress messages from type in batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I've been writing a batch script (which I do very rarely).

I want to suppress anything that I do not explicitly `echo`.

For everything thus far, using

`>nul 2>&1`

works to suppress messages from `stderr` and `stdout`.

However, when I try to apply the same principle to `type`, the command does not execute...

`type header.tmp geo.tmp > geo.txt`

is the command I would like to suppress.

Any ideas??

Comment: You could even redirect a whole block of code to `nul` like `> nul 2>&1 ( ... )`, and then explicitly redirect every intended output within that block to `> con`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're trying to prevent it from showing the filenames. You can do this by using

```
type header.tmp geo.tmp > geo.txt 2>nul
```

as type sends the filenames when receiving multiple files to the error output, `2>`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I guess I should probably learn what these things actually suppress before I move on, but thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @AndersHokinson To know more about redirection/supressing commands, take a look at [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Answer (score -1):

I normally suppress echo from the outset of a batch script with...

```
@echo off
```

Turning it back on at the end with...

```
@echo on
```

And during the execution of the script, I then only echo what I wish to echo regarding its execution. Doing this saves you having to send everything to NUL. Although, you will still have to redirect the std output or err output of certain commands to nul, such as in the case of the type command.

Comment: echo on/off is used for showing/hiding the commands that get executed, not for showing/hiding the actual output of those commands, please see [Command Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Yes. Exactly. He then only needs to direct the output of the commands he DOES wish to see rather than seeing all the other stuff. Such as sending the err output of type to nul. I've updated my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: @echo off **does not redirect output.** It prevents the commands themselves from showing up in cmd, **but not the output**. For instance, `echo hello` will still show `hello` in the cmd, but not `C:>echo hello` the line above it. However, `echo hello >nul` will not show `hello` in the output

Comment: I'm well aware of that. As I said, I've updated my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: You can redirect the batch file when starting it, then it applies to what is in the batch file. Also acts as if `Echo off` has been set. You can also do this trick with the `call` command.